# "Store metadata "CurrentBind" is not valid" in debug of ClickOnce application

Tags: .net, exception, clickonce

When I try to access "Application.CommonAppDataPath" i get this error message:

> System.Deployment: Store metadata
>   "CurrentBind" is not valid

Stack Trace:

> at
>   System.Deployment.Application.ComponentStore.GetPropertyString(DefinitionAppId
>   appId, String propName)

This is only in Debug. When running as an actual published clickonce application it works fine.

How can I get rid of this exception when debugging locally?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I had a similar issue (like jpierson's comment) with the same exception '"CurrentBind" not valid' on ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed. I had unchecked "Options|Debugging|General|Just My Code". After checking it back all worked fine.

NOTE: Some other discussion threads had suggested reinstalling VS2010. I did that but did not help. I don't know if reinstalling was also the fator.

Answer (score 2):

I intentionally set VS to break on CLR exceptions.  You certainly can mask this exception by only debugging your code but, it is still a valid bug that I'd like an explanation for.  MS should be the forerunner on writing solid code.

Answer (score 1):

[`ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.deployment.application.applicationdeployment.isnetworkdeployed.aspx) (in the System.Deployment.Application namespace) is a boolean property that returns `true` if the application was launched with ClickOnce.

```
if (ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed)
{
    //CommonAppPath code
}
```

What are you trying to do with CommonAppDataPath?  Depending on what you're trying to accomplish, we could probably come up with something that will work no matter how the app is launched.

Comment: I am saving the settings.xml-file for my program in Application.CommonAppDataPath\ProgramName\ path.

Comment: Strangely I'm getting the same error that the original poster described when attempting to read the ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed property.

Store metadata "CurrentBind" is not valid.

Comment: Me too ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed just give the same error. Followed by an "Application is not installed" error.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem. Thanks to mkale for pointing me in the right direction.

I had installed the Reflector VS Addin a few days ago, and at some point it asked about changing the Just My Code option. I had completely forgotten about it, and have been messing around with this problem for the last two days!

At the same time I also had a problem with FileLoadException - which was reporting in the Fusion log that "WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Revision Number". Initially I got around that problem by setting the assembly version to 1.1.0.0 instead of as 1.1.*.

However, once having set the Just My Code option, all these problems disappeared.