# Store metadata "CurrentBind" is not valid. Error

Tags: .net, deployment, clickonce, debugging

In the context of a click-once application that is being debugged locally with exception breaking on "Thrown" turned on in VS2010, I am experiencing the following error:

```
Deployment Exception: "Store metadata "CurrentBind" is not valid."
   at System.Deployment.Application.ComponentStore.GetPropertyString(DefinitionAppId appId, String propName)
```

when I execute the following line of code:

```
if (System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed)
```

This exception is being caught and handled by .net code, and the application will not crash after experiencing this error.  Unfortunately, this error is followed up by:

```
InvalidDeploymentException: "Application is not installed"
       at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment..ctor(String fullAppId)
```

If I continue to wade through the exceptions, I get another error:

```
SynchronizationLockException: "Object synchronization method was called from an unsynchronized block of code"
       at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.SynchronizedLifetimeManager.TryExit()
@ ProvidedContainer.RegisterInstance(LoggerFacade);
```

and finally:

```
ConfigurationErrorsException: "This element is not currently associated with any context"
    at System.Configuration.ConfigurationElement.get_EvaluationContext()
```

in the constructor of

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
public partial class InfrastructureDataServiceClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<Infrastructure.DataServices.IInfrastructureDataService>, Infrastructure.DataServices.IInfrastructureDataService 
    {
        public InfrastructureDataServiceClient() {
    }
}
```

These errors are all handled by the .net framework code and don't ripple into the application, but as long as I have the option to break on exception "Thrown" I continue to go through these errors until I lose patience and choose to break only on unhandled exceptions, at which point the app fully loads.

This has happened to me in the past, and at that time I had to completely re-install visual studio, but it worked fine after that.  I'd rather not do that, as it is time consuming and my VS installation is pretty customized.  Also, my co-workers are not experiencing the same error, so that tells me that there is something unique about my environment.

I experienced a visual studio hang recently when debugging, and had to kill the devenv process, that might play a role, but it's hard to say because I recently turned on the break on thrown option.  I've already tried to delete the suo files, but that had no effect.

I have the following addons installed:
Resharper, .Net Reflector, Team Explorer, TFS Power Tools, Theme Manager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did to resolve this issue was reinstall visual studio. After doing that, the exceptions went away.

Comment: This is wrong. It is a simple debugging option you need to uncheck.  Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1914531/store-metadata-currentbind-is-not-valid-in-debug-of-clickonce-application

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a lot of other people have solved this problem just by disabling breaking on this exception - see [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wcf/thread/2620084b-a77b-4c77-b9ce-725fbea1df55/), [here](http://zamd.net/2008/04/06/configurationerrorsexception-this-element-is-not-currently-associated-with-any-context/), [here](http://discoveringdotnet.alexeyev.org/2009/06/this-element-is-not-currently.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7118099/configurationerrorsexception-this-element-is-not-currently-associated-with-any-c), for example.  Nobody seems to have any idea what use this exception is, though.

I should add that I had to add the exception manually to my Debug/Exceptions list - it didn't appear by default.

Comment: What I did to resolve this issue was reinstall visual studio.  After doing that, the exceptions went away.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I just reset current settings in Tools/Import and Export Settings in Visual Studio 2010 menu. I hope it works for you!