# ConfigurationErrorsException: This element is not currently associated with any context

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, exception, configuration

I am getting strange exception which seems to me is related to WCF configuration object but what is wrong is completely unclear to me

A first chance exception of type 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException' occurred in System.Configuration.dll

Additional information: This element is not currently associated with any context

```
ServiceModelSectionGroup serviceConfigs =
ServiceModelSectionGroup.GetSectionGroup(config);

ServiceElement serviceConfig = 
serviceConfigs.Services.Services[serviceType.ToString()]; << here exception
```

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Looks like a lot of other people have solved this problem just by disabling breaking on this exception - see [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wcf/thread/2620084b-a77b-4c77-b9ce-725fbea1df55/), [here](http://zamd.net/2008/04/06/configurationerrorsexception-this-element-is-not-currently-associated-with-any-context/), [here](http://discoveringdotnet.alexeyev.org/2009/06/this-element-is-not-currently.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4092645/store-metadata-currentbind-is-not-valid-error/7220736#7220736), for example.  Nobody seems to have any idea what use this exception is, though.

I should add that I had to add the exception manually to my Debug/Exceptions list - it didn't appear by default.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue by deleting everything in the bin folder and rebuilding the solution.

Comment: I know this question is somewhat old, but I figured this might be of use to other users with the issue.